# Google Sheets - If the colour in one cell, matches the colour in another cell, print the thing in the other cell

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I'm basically trying to create google sheet that looks up colours in cells. I've been trying to find a script or formula that can do this but have had no luck. Anyone have any idea on how I can do this?

Here's my Google sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19EQdldGAKo0t-9SrmGbPgL9wNVg-Q9gK_pFcPDaiSJc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background colors can't be read with a formula, but this script can handle it:

```
function colorCells() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var lr=s.getLastRow()//get last result data row
  var legendVal=s.getRange(2, 2, 4, 2).getValues()//get legend values
  var legendBG=s.getRange(2, 1, 4, 1).getBackgrounds()//get legend backgrounds
  var result=s.getRange(10, 1, lr-9, 1).getValues()// get result values
  for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){ //loop result values
    for(var j=0;j<legendVal.length;j++){//loop legend values
      if(result[i][0]==legendVal[j][0]){//compare values
         s.getRange(i+10, 2).setBackground(legendBG[j][0])//set background color
  }}}}
```